# Use Dynamically Generated Version Number as Release Name

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a build which has a custom shell step that dynamically generates a version number that I'd like to set as the Release Name in the same project. I have some nuanced logic that decides the construction and increment of the build number.

I've dabbled in trying to set an output parameter as part of the build step. But I can't get that to be the part of the Release Name.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add a small snippet to your step/task/script that logs the required name to the logs:

```js
const value = "Whatever you want" 
console.log(`##vso[release.updatereleasename]${value}`);
```

The above is Javascript, but for Bash it would be very similar:

```bash
set VALUE="Whatever you want" 
echo "##vso[release.updatereleasename]$VALUE"
```

Or use my [Variable Toolbox to set the value](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jessehouwing.jessehouwing-vsts-variable-tasks):

```yaml
- task: VariableSetTask@3
  inputs:
    variableName: 'release.releasename'
    value: 'Release-$(somevariable)'
```